# Escribir archivos y modificarlos con .bat dentro de un ciclo

Tags: batch

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar a resolver un problema que tengo a la hora de escribir varias entradas del usuario en un archivo utilizando un ciclo FOR.

En mi codigo, le pido al usuario que ingrese los detalles de una base de datos, paso a paso. Primero pido el nombre de la base de datos, despues se debe de ingresar el numero de tablas que desea crear y posteriormente dentro del ciclo, se solicita que se ingresen los nombres de cada una de las tablas.

Los resultados de los inputs del usuario se van escribiendo en un archivo SQL. Mi problema esta en que no se escriben correctamente las variables que el usuario esta ingresando. Esto ocurre durante el ciclo, la variable %contador% se queda vacia en la primera iteracion SIEMPRE y las siguientes iteraciones corresponden a valores anteriores de la variable. Aqui dejo la parte de codigo que me esta dando problemas.

```
@ECHO OFF
set contador=1
set /p System=Ingresa el nombre del Sistema:
set /p noTables=Ingresa el numero de Tablas que deseas crear en la Base de Datos:
set finalizar=);
echo CREATE DATABASE %System%; > DB.sql
echo USE DATABASE %System%; >> DB.sql
:cycle1
if %contador% LEQ %noTables% (
    set /p tableName=Nombre de la siguiente tabla:
    set nextTable=%tableName% 
    echo CREATE TABLE %nextTable% ^( >> DB.sql
    set /a contador=contador+1
    goto :cycle1
) else (
    goto :salir
)
:salir
pause
```

Suponiendo que el usuario ingreso "3" en el numero de tablas y al ingresar los nombres de las tablas como "tabla 1" "tabla 2" "tabla 3". Este es el resultado que se escribe en el archivo SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE Sistema; 
USE DATABASE Sistema; 
CREATE TABLE  ( 
CREATE TABLE   ( 
CREATE TABLE tabla 1  (
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. He probado tu código. Curiosamente al ejecutarlo por segunda vez si te escribe el nombre de las tablas. Por ejemplo, la primera vez tecleé Curso como nombre del sistema y el número de tablas puse 2. Al teclear el nombre de las tablas no lo escribe, solo al intentarlo la segunda vez. Algo así: 
CREATE DATABASE Curso; 
USE DATABASE Curso; 
CREATE TABLE Emp  (  
CREATE TABLE Depto  (